# windows doesn't startup when I install visual studio emulator for android

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-emulator

I installed Xamarin with Visual studio 2015, they worked well until I installed visual studio emulator for android, every time when I install it, windows couldn't start and stuck at windows logo for hours, Windows couldn't boot unless I restore system..

Do you have any suggestion to solve this problem ? or are there any emulator compatible with visual studio instead ?

p.s. my OS is windows 8.1 x64

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever been able to get one VS Android emulator to work, but that is mainly because I use VM for Windows and only have 4GB ram assigned to it, and many of the emulator images need almost all of that.

That said, Google's Android emulators have gotten pretty good, especially if you install the Intel HAXM Accelerator included in the Android SDK. Instructions to install the HAXM Accelerator:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

And also make sure you update your Android SDK in the SdK Manager to get all of the latest stuff (with the exception of Preview N packages as Xamarin does not fully support N yet, and also do not install Build Tools version 24. there are issues with those build tools and Xamarin at this point. See https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this happens due to the Hyper-V. Microsoft emulator requires Hyper-V but if your computer doesn't support it for a reason or another that might very well happen.
To check this theory, enable Hyper-V by yourself (Programs and Features/Turn Windows features on or off, Hyper-V/Hyper-V Platform).

Other emulators don't require Hyper-V, so, if that's a problem you can still pick among Google's (free), Xamarin's (free) and Genymotion (commercial).